# Getting the max for an Api json data in react

Tags: reactjs, json, api, dataset, max

I have fetched an Api data which is "PRICES" , and I'm trying to get the maximum for it but this function is not working , I would appreciate any help !

```js
const pricedata = {
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: '#0000',
            barPercentage: 2,
            barThickness: 5,
            data: PRICES,
            label: 'Update in prices',
            maxBarThickness: 10
        },
    ],
};

function findMax(PRICES) {
    if (!PRICES) {
        return;
    }
    return Math.max(...PRICES);
}

console.log(findMax())
```

Comment: what is the value of `PRICES` variable?

Comment: @Dylan Its numbers

Comment: @Dylan yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the "price data" where you have PRICES in the data and added a 2nd chunk of data for illustration.

The code below loops over each "dataset" and, finds the max price and adds it as a new key called "maxPrice". Then it prints them out. This is just one way.

```
const pricedata = {
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: "#0000",
      barPercentage: 2,
      barThickness: 5,
      data: [1, 10, 30, 7, 42, 12],
      label: "Update in prices",
      maxBarThickness: 10
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: "#0000",
      barPercentage: 2,
      barThickness: 5,
      data: [11, 70, 18, 17, 24, 12],
      label: "Update in prices",
      maxBarThickness: 10
    }
  ]
};

function findMax(PRICES) {
  if (!PRICES) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Math.max(...PRICES);
}

pricedata.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
  dataset.maxPrice = findMax(dataset.data);
});

pricedata.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
  console.log('max price is', dataset.maxPrice);
});
```

Update:
Use a reducer to get the max of all the products...

```
const maxOfAllProducts = pricedata.datasets.reduce((accumulator, current) => Math.max(current.maxPrice, accumulator),0);
console.log('max of all products', maxOfAllProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the PRICES variable in the function call on the last line

```
  let PRICES = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
 

  function findMax(PRICES) {
    if (!PRICES) {
        return;
    }
    return Math.max(...PRICES);
}

console.log(findMax(PRICES)) // outputs 10
```

OR remove that variable in the function

```
  let PRICES = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
 

  function findMax() {
    if (!PRICES) {
        return;
    }
    return Math.max(...PRICES);
}

console.log(findMax()) //outputs 10
```